# Is it possible to convert bootstrap classes into pure css?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

Can I convert bootstrap classes to pure css?

Something like convert 'class="container-sm' to normal css.

I would like to know the CSS that contains the "container-sm" class in bootstrap

```
<div class="container-sm">100% wide until small breakpoint</div>
<div class="container-md">100% wide until medium breakpoint</div>
```

Comment: Why wouldn't it be since Bootstrap classes ***are*** CSS?

Comment: CSS is based on classes so what are you asking exactly?

Comment: Pep wants inline bootstrap css code.

Comment: Can you clarify how what you have now is not "normal CSS"?

Comment: I would like to know the CSS that contains the "container-sm" class in bootstrap @HazardousGlitch

Comment: just open developer tools with F12

Answer (score 4):

Bootstrap classes are CSS so there is nothing to convert.

My best guess is that you want to see the actual CSS rules of each class to understand what they do.

If that is the case, you can just right click and inspect the element you want. You will see a pane with all the css rules applied to the element you want to see.

Comment: He means converting a bootstrap file into inline CSS styles, so i think there is something to convert.